# Element.Click not executed when using PhantomJS selenium webdriver in .Net

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am using our existing tool that works perfectly using the Firefox and Chrome implementations of the Selenium IWebdriver.

I am now doing some experimentation using the PhantomJS implementation.
So far so good. However, as soon as I want to click a button it does nothing.

I can retrieve the element, however, looking closer at its properties the 'Selected' property states the following:

```
    Error Message => 'Element is not selectable' caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Close","Host":"localhost:37704"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/selected","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"selected","directory":"/","path":"/selected","relative":"/selected","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/selected","queryKey":{},"chunks":["selected"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/fcaf88a0-40b4-11e3-960d-bdce3224aacf/element/%3Awdc%3A1383063211142/selected"}
```

I would gather this is the cause that my click is not executed, however, I cannot make heads or tails from this error message. using Google did not help either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try increasing the size of browser window to (1200, 800) while using phantomjs. I had a same issue and it got solved by this.

Comment: Please share your code and HTML of page, only then we can get to the actual problem.

Comment: If you locate your element with ID, try to locate it differently. I had VERY STRAGE situations where locating using ID haven't worked with GhostDriver.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys, 
I am sorry I did not get back to this.

We decided not to use this driver, despite the possibility of speeding up the test process.

Answer (score 8):

We had a lot of similar issues with PhantomJS.

So, couple of steps to figure out what the root cause to it

1. Set you screen size (as suggested in comments; PhantomJS uses 400x300 by default):

   ```
   driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080); //Size is type in System.Drawing"
   ```
2. Use to verify that your element is actually visible:

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver,
   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id(login))));
   ```
3. Click on the element with Javascript

   ```
   IJavaScriptExecutor js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
   js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", buttonToClick); //buttonToClick is IWebElement
   ```

For **Java** it would be as follows:

1. Screen size

   ```
   driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
   ```
2. Verifying element is visible

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("LOCATOR")));
   ```
3. Clicking with JS

   ```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", buttonToClick); //buttonToClick is WebElement
   ```

Comment: how i can do the same equivalent in java?

Comment: @B.J.A.A.Edited the answer with Java solution